# Parameter Problem while running sql query in C#

Tags: .net

Error :

> The SqlParameterCollection only accepts non-null SqlParameter
>   type objects, not String objects

This is the error I'm getting when I run this code

```
MenuItem masterItem = new MenuItem((string)masterRow["Parentitem"]);
string mp =(string) masterItem.Value;

SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
parameter.ParameterName = "@mp";

parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
parameter.Value = mp;

string q = "select aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser.hasRights from Menu, aspnet_Users, 
            aspnet_Paths, aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser 
            where Menu.Parentitem = @mp 
            and Menu.Url = aspnet_Paths.Path 
            and aspnet_Paths.PathId = aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser.PathId 
            and aspnet_Users.UserName ='admin' 
            and aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser.UserId = aspnet_Users.userId ";

SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(q, conn);
cm.Parameters.Add(mp);
string b = (string)cm.ExecuteScalar();
```

I'm getting the exception when I'm adding parameter to the command.. Can u let me know the mistake..

Comment: Free tip of the day: I would try to avoid the legacy-style JOIN's by just having `from Menu, aspnet_Users, aspnet_Paths, aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser` - this is very dangerous, if you ever miss one JOIN condition in the WHERE clause, you end up with a cartesian product! Also: your actual WHERE clause gets cluttered up with unnecessary conditions that really only serve as JOIN conditions.....

Comment: Instead, use the ANSI standard JOIN syntax which clearly marks the type of JOIN and has the JOIN condition right there where it belongs - much easier to read! (also: use table aliases - they make your queries much easier to read, too!): 
`FROM dbo.Menu m 
 INNER JOIN dbo.aspnet_Paths p ON m.Url = p.Path
 INNER JOIN dbo.aspnet_PersonalizationPerUser ppu ON p.PathId = ppu.PathId 
 INNER JOIN dbo.aspnet_Users usr ON ppu.UserId = u.userId 
 WHERE Menu.Parentitem = @mp 
 AND aspnet_Users.UserName = 'admin'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
cm.Parameters.Add(mp);
```

to this:

```
cm.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```